# Mongodb Discrepancy between space actually used and space available

Tags: mongodb

I'm not sure if this has already been asked but I'm facing a weird issue in MongoDB 4.2.8(Standalone).

We have a single collection running which uses a TTL index to delete all documents that are older than 24 hours.

Now the weird issue -
`df -h` shows the our external mongod volume as 94GB used,
however `du -hsx` shows that the data is only 85GB and logs are 0KB.

Why is there a discrepancy of around 9GB on the disk?
I read that `db.compact` could release free space to the OS but we need to be 100% sure there will be zero downtime with the operation.

Could anyone guide us on how to release the space with no downtime?

EDIT -

I just ran `db.stats()` in my MongoDB instance this is the output -

```
"objects" : 74749716,
"avgObjSize" : 3462.7832923539136,
"dataSize" : 258842067673,
"storageSize" : 85391945728,
"numExtents" : 0,
"indexes" : 13,
"indexSize" : 3864145920,
"scaleFactor" : 1,
"fsUsedSize" : 100955877376,
"fsTotalSize" : 107346903040,
"ok" : 1
```

The question being how is storageSize and fsUsedSize different?

Answer (score 0):

As your two space readings both come from the OS environment (neither `df` nor `du` inspect the contents inside your database files) this is an OS/filesystem matter not a MongoDB one, so https://superuser.com/ or https://serverfault.com/ would be better places to search for an answer (do search first rather than just asking, this is likely to be a common issue so most  likely will have been asked and answered multiple times).

A quick summary of some possible factors resulting in the discrepancy include:

1. Linux native filesystems (ext2, ext3, ext4) usually default to reserve some space for the root user to aid clean-up when things become full or near full and as a small anti-fragmentation measure. This default is often 5% which on large volumes can be a lot of space. [See here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7950/reserved-space-for-root-on-a-filesystem-why) amongst other references for more information including how to alter this reservation.
2. `du` might not be hidden “`.`” files.
3. Are you running `du` at the root of the filesystem? If not there may be files above that it is not counting (`df` always reflects the whole filesystem).
4. If there are mount points within this filesystem, there could be files hidden by the mount that are not being counted by `du`.

Comment: I actually have gone through a few answers but they were generally related to replica sets rather than a standalone server.
One suggestion was also about a previous mount underneath the current mount point but that was empty.
1. I'm using XFS and there was no reserved space when I created the volume.
2. I did consider that as well however ll -a and du -hsx .[^.]* didn't find any hidden folders.
3. I'm running du -hsx at the mount point for the external volume.
4. Already checked for hidden files.

Could you advise whether compact would require downtime?

Comment: I don't know ab out downtime but I expect that compact will make no difference anyway because the discrepancy you have described between what is reported by `df` and `du` seems to be either in the filesystem or how those tools are reading it, not the database file contents. If Mondo uses sparse files then `du`'s `--apparent-size` option may be useful and give different results. Other than that, try asking on SU or SF.